# Form authentication not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am trying to make a registration and login form using javascript, it's like, once a user registers the data is stored in an array and then that data is used to authenticate the user and display the user details on the page, after logging in the alert is not popping, Please help! thanks in advance.
Following is my register.html and controller.js-

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Register</title>
    <style>
    article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
        display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Please enter data</h1> FirstName:
        <input id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" />
        <br> LastName :
        <input id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="LastName" />
        <br> Email ID :
        <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        <br> UserName :
        <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="UserName" />
        <br> Password :
        <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Register" onclick="insert()" />
    </form>
    <!--Login form-->
    <div id="demo" style="display:none">
        <div class="container">
            <form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
                <label>User Name :</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
                <label>Password :</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
                <input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.display='block'">Login!</button>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script src="D:/Xperience/js/controller.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**controller.js**

```
var users = [];
localStorage.setItem("keyforusers", JSON.stringify(users));
var idInput = (users.length) + 1;
var firstnameInput = document.getElementById("firstname");
var lastnameInput = document.getElementById("lastname");
var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
var usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
var passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");
var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

function userdetails(id, firstname, lastname, email, username, password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

function insert() {
    var user = new userdetails(idInput.value, firstnameInput.value, lastnameInput.value, emailInput.value, usernameInput.value, passwordInput.value);
    users.push(user);

    //Clear the fields
    firstnameInput.value = "";
    lastnameInput.value = "";
    emailInput.value = "";
    usernameInput.value = "";
    passwordInput.value = "";
}

function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    ulen = users.length;
    for (i = 0; i < ulen; i++) {
        if (username == users[i].username && password == users[i].password) {
            alert("Logged in successfully");
        }
    }
    username.value = "";
    password.value = "";
}
```

Comment: you are using a form but are not using form submit, i have had similar error where the browser wont allow you to send the password like this...  try changing your '<form>' to a '<div>' and test if it works

Comment: I tried this..but still not working..

Comment: Have you got any errors in your console? two things i spotted: 'ulen' (Is not declared should be 'var ulen') and `enter code here` should not be there

Comment: Did not get any errors in console.. yes, I missed 'var ulen'..thanks